# Angular: wait for location.href to complete using $q.deffer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, download

I'm trying to display a UI loading bar for when the user downloads a file. The download file code already works, and I already have a UI progress indicator configured with Angular so its just a matter of setting the bool value to true or false to display/remove the progress bar. My code looks like this:

```
$scope.getCompletedJobs = function () {

    $rootScope.blockUI = true;

    var params = {
        StartDate: $scope.StartDate,
        EndDate: $scope.EndDate
    };

    location.href = apiEntry.linkHref('get-completed-transfer-jobs') + "?" + $httpParamSerializer(params);

    $rootScope.blockUI = false;
};
```

My problem is obvious, the location.href returns immediately after it gets executed, causing  $rootScope.blockUI = false; to executing, which effective $rootScope.blockUI = false; only when the location.href completes. I believe I need to use some sort of deffer/promise pattern, but Im not entirely sure how to implement this using Angular.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

The completed working code now looks like this

```
$scope.getCompletedJobs = function () {

    $rootScope.blockUI = true;

    var params = {
        StartDate: $scope.StartDate,
        EndDate: $scope.EndDate
    };

    $http.get(apiEntry.linkHref('get-completed-transfer-jobs') + "?" + $httpParamSerializer(params))
        .then(function (response) {
            //do something here with the response
            $rootScope.blockUI = false;

            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(response.data);
            a.target = '_blank';
            a.download = 'CompletedTransferJobs.csv';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably don't want to redirect the page to the api endpoint, but instead a make a request there,

```
$scope.getCompletedJobs = function () {

        $rootScope.blockUI = true;

        var params = {
            StartDate: $scope.StartDate,
            EndDate: $scope.EndDate
        };

$http.get(apiEntry.linkHref('get-completed-transfer-jobs') + "?" + $httpParamSerializer(params)).then(function(response) {
//do something here with the response
 $rootScope.blockUI = true;
})



    };
```

Comment: The progress loader functions as expected using this approuch, but the file does not download anymore. What am I missing in your code? Thanks

Comment: I see.  You can't really have a loader for this then.  When you think about it you make a request to a page actually not an api response really.  So you can use location.href again, but just don't use loader.  There is no point.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sertvicename.getData().then(function(data){
    //do what you want with data here
   //false logic come here after

   $rootScope.blockUI = false;      

 }).catch(fucntion(){

 //if any error 
 })
```